# Any plugin for c++ editor?

Tags: java, c++, ide, editor, anjuta

I am developing a standalone java desktop application. In that application I am giving user to create his own c++ file or modify the existing ones...But currently I am using Jtextarea as an editor for editing or creating c++ file. I actually want user to give some IDE like editor(such as in Anjuta) so that it becomes more  user friendly. Is it possible to use any plugin in my app for c++ editing and if it is then which and how to use it??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Eclipse framework.   It will have more features that you can include in your app then you have time to produce yourself.

Comment: my application is almost developed...is it possible to include any plugin for c++ editor in my java code??

Comment: Yes you can include pieces of Eclipse into your project.